# Facebook App Feed Dialog Big Image

Tags: facebook

What's the way of posting a bigger image than this small thumbnail through my Facebook App?

The following code creates a Feed Dialog, but I actually want to have a bigger picture for this Feed Dialog thumbnail.

```
FB.init({appId: "MY_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true}); 
function postToFeed() 
    {
    var obj = { method: 'feed', link: 'apps.facebook.com/myapplink/';
    , picture: 'com/image.jpg';, name: ' ', caption: ' ', description: ' ' };
    function callback(response) {} FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
`$pic_path = "/tmp/".$filename.".jpg";

$message = 'hello world';

$dat=array(
            'source' => "@".$pic_path,
            'message' => $message."  ".$sharelink,
            );

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos',"POST",$dat);`
```

Comment: how can i connect the above code with my postToFeed Javascript function?